# grep with regular expression in command line

Tags: regex, grep

I'm interested in finding pattern like %CHILD_NAME%, %PARENT_NAME%, %ADDRESS% using regex and preferably recursively in the current directory
Following is the grep command I am using

```
grep -r "(.[A-Z]+[_]*[A-Z]+%)" *
```

When I use the same regex above at http://www.regexr.com, it does match %CHILD_NAME% but my command is not able to find this pattern in any file in current or sub directory.

Comment: If you are using basic regular expression mode (no `-E` or `-P`), you need to use `\+` to match one or more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, grep uses basic regular expression and meta-characters like `+` lose their meaning and need to be escaped. Remove the capturing group `( )`, escape the `+` quantifiers and use an actual `%` in place of `.`

```
grep -r '%[A-Z]\+[_]*[A-Z]\+%' *
```

Although, you could probably use the following:

```
grep -r "%[A-Z_]\+%" *
```

Comment: This works. Other answers worked too but this does the job in less characters and is relatively easy to understand hence accepting as answer.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you regex is too generic: at matches `CHILD_NAME%` (without `%` in the front) as well. A better regex is:

```
"%[A-Z]+(_[A-Z]+)*%"
```

Next, it is advisable to use the `perl` interpretation of regexes using the `-P` flag:

```
grep -r -P "%[A-Z]+(_[A-Z]+)*%" .
```

You can also use the `-E` flag here (extensive mode).